# xCode 4.3 static library cross project reference

Tags: ios, xcode4, static, shared-libraries

I have problems using my own static library.

Here is what I did:

**Static Library**

1.) I created a new project with "cocoa static library" template

2.) I added a simple test file "LibraryTest" to that project

3.) I defined in "LibraryTest" a public function "testFunction"

4.) Under "Targets"->"Build Phases"->"Copy Headers", I added LibraryTest.h to "public"

5.) I build the library and in folder "Products" the previously red marked library file turns black. So I guess everything worked fine

**New Project**

1.) I created a new Project with "Empty Application" template

2.) I dragged my static library to the new project

3.) I am importing "LibraryTest.h" to my AppDelegate with #import "LibraryTest.h". The import autocompletes

4.) Unfortunetely if I try to compile it says, that the "LibraryTest.h" could not be found and therefore no build.

Here you can see a [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk9if.jpg) of my "New Project" project explorer window in xCode.
The library "libJRL_jumero_iOS_library" is still red. So I guess the library can not be found and this maybe the reason. But I don't know why it isn't build.

Anybody ideas what went wrong?

Regards,
Jan

**EDIT 11.06.2012:**

If I use "@class LibraryTest;", I can compile and the function is called, e. g.:

LibraryTest *libraryTest = [[LibraryTest alloc] init];
[libraryTest testFunction];

But I get warnings:
Receiver LibraryTest.h is a forward class and corresponding interface may not exist.
Instance method -testFunction not found.

Answer (score 0):

You do have to drag the h file as well in your project.
Usually when you build a static library, you then provide the .a file as well as the public h files.
All that bundle must be imported in your project, otherwise you wouldn't be able to see the interface and the methods declarations.

Comment: Hi bettola, thanks for your answer, but that is exactly what I did as I described under 4.). The .a file is red in my "New Project". I think its not build but I don't know why.

Comment: It seems from the snapshot that you didn't add the library as a static library but as an imported project. I expected to see just one xcode project, with the imported .a inside and the headers....but from the snapshot I see two projects: Base and libJRL

Comment: how do I add it as a static library? What I did was drag&drop the static library project into my "new project" project ...

Comment: You just need to drag the .a file in your project as well as the header files...not the whole xcode project

Comment: To be more clear...once you have compiled your static library, in xcode, you can see the folder called "product" in the tree with your build inside it...click with the right button and select "show in finder"...there you find the .a file to add to the project where you wanna include that library. Remember to import the header files as well

Comment: is there also a way that my static library gets automatically recompiled when I debug/test/release my "new project". That would be great and it would be also good to get linking in the code working to my static library project (cmd+left mouse click on property/method or class )